# from where can i obtain "built-in-ds" sample project in smart GWT

Tags: smartgwt

In the quick start guide for Smart GWT, it says that I should open the "built-in-ds" sample project included in the Smart GWT SDK under samples/built-in-ds.

However this project is not there in the downloadeded SDK. (The latest version of Smart GWT is 2.5)

From where can I obtain this sample ?(as well as other samples- currently the samples folder only has 'showcase' in it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "built-in-ds" Sample is included in Smartgwt Enterprise Edition only.

[Here](http://www.smartclient.com/product/download-bounce.jsp?product=smartgwt&license=eval&version=2.5) you can download a full-featured 60 day trial version for free. In `smartgwtee/samples` you will find what you are looking for.

But the LGPL version brings a lot of samples as well. You can find them under `samples/Showcase/src/com/smartgwt/sample/showcase/client/[nameOfTheSample]`.